# Javascript: if 'abstract' is a reserved word why I am still able to use it as an identifier?

Tags: javascript, identifier, reserved-words

I am reading a book about JavaScript where I read about reserved words, I tried all the reserved words to us as an identifier but no one is allowed except 'abstract', I am still able to use 'abstract' as an identifier even it is a reserved word! I tried Internet Explorer, Chrome, Firefox and it is working as an identifier, why is it still allowed as an identifier even it is a reserved word?
Thanks

```js
  function myFunction(a, b) {
      abstract = a+b;
   alert("Sum = "+abstract);
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>TestScript</title>
</head>
<body>
 <button onclick="myFunction(20, 5)">Try it</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Some of the reserved words are not used in JavaScript. The logic is that they are reserved words in other languages.

Comment: `abstract` is not a reserved word.

Comment: Sounds like your book is out of date.

Comment: By definition, a reserved word can't be used as an identifier. The list is in the ES5 specification, [*§7.6.1*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6.1), "abstract" isn't one of them.

Comment: If it's calling `abstract` reserved, then it's out of date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are [tons of "future" reserved words](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords) which aren't actually reserved, because the don't yet do anything. Many of them will never do anything.

For example, `synchronized` is also a reserved word, but `var synchronized = true` probably works in most browsers. Same for `native`, `boolean`, `transient` etc.

```js
var native, boolean, float, await, synchronized;

native = boolean = float = await = synchronized = "blah";

document.write(native, boolean, float, await, synchronized); // blahblahblahblahblah
```

Comment: I feel this is missing the point that `synchronized`, `abstract` etc. aren't actually reserved words anymore, so aren't listed in the ECMA standard

Comment: @Miguel There are *current* "future" reserved words that still work, like `var await = 3`. It's not about these things not being reserved words *anymore*, browsers haven't stopped supporting earlier versions of JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

My suspicion is that the book you're reading is using an older version of JavaScript when `abstract` was still a reserved keyword. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Future_reserved_keywords) `abstract` is *reserved as a future keyword by older ECMAScript specifications (ECMAScript 1 till 3).*

Here's the list of reserved keywords as of ES6, which is the standard your browsers are likely to be conforming to (again from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Future_reserved_keywords)):

```
break       case        class
catch       const       continue
debugger    default     delete
do          else        export
extends     finally     for
function    if          import
in          instanceof  let 
new         return      super
switch      this        throw       
try         typeof      var         
void        while       with
yield
```

Comment: Modern browsers should implement ECMAScript 5.1 and perhaps parts of ES6 (which is still a draft).

Comment: Even browsers that don't support ES6 still have things like `class` as reserved keywords. But since `abstract` is only reserved according to an old standard, browsers will allow it

Comment: @mguel—many ECMAScript ed 3 browsers allowed future reserved words as identifiers, e.g. IE 6 allows *abstract*, *int*, *private*, etc.

Comment: This isn't about "outdated" reserved words, several in your list of "currently" reserved words in ES6 still work. `var let` and `var yield` both work in Chrome. Browsers are seemingly choosing not to actually reserve some of the words that have absolutely no functionality attached to them (yet).

Answer (score 1):

A while ago, abstract was singled out for future use in a later version of the language. However, it is still not yet a reserved word in the current version of the language. I would suggest not using it for the sake of future compatibility

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar